# javascript run xmlhttp php script 404 not found

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a .js file run a .php file in the same folder. I'm using `XMLHttpRequest`. Currently, the .js script is running with a node server.

I've tried a variety of things for the url to get the .php file.

- `my_file.php` results in a `"404 (Not Found)"`
- `//InsertAbsolutePathHere/tests/my_file.php` results in a `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`
- `file:///InsertAbsolutePathHere/tests/my_file.php` results in a `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

If I use the first option (relative path), I notice that the final url starts with "`localhost:3000/tests`". I can view the file in Chrome just fine when I use the absolute path, but the `localhost:3000/tests` version shows me a "`Cannot GET`" message.
However, if I use a relative path for `index.html`, or any other html page for that matter, my code seems to find the file just fine. It only throws a 404 when it's a relative path to a php file.

Here's my file organization:

- Documents

  - js

    - index.js (the file where I want to call my php from)
  - tests

    - index.html
    - my_file.php

I have a feeling my relative path isn't working because I'm running a node server, and that the server isn't playing nice with php files. Can someone confirm this?

How do I get my php script to load? Also, what's the difference between the two absolute path options? Why are they returning different error messages?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's my code (part of which was taken from another post)

```
function drawError() {
    var container = document.getElementById('output');
    console.log('Bummer: there was an error!');
}
// handles the response, adds the html
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    console.log(responseText);
}
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
    var req = false;
    try{
        // most browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
    console.log("XML request failed.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
    if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4) {
            return req.status === 200 ? success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}
var urlString1 = 'my_file.php?' + encodeURIComponent('game_id') + '=0&' + encodeURIComponent('client_timestamp') + '=10';
//var urlString2 = '//Users/Emma/Documents/tests/my_file.php';
//var urlString3 = 'file:///Users/Emma/Documents/tests/my_file.php';
console.log(urlString);
var urlRequest = getRequest(
    urlString, // URL for the PHP file 
    drawOutput,  // handle successful request 
    drawError    // handle error
);
console.log(urlRequest);
```

Comment: Well, you say that everything is in the same folder, so why wouldn't you just use `my_file.php` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that all of my php and index files that I wanted to load are in the same folder, but the .js file that I'm calling them from are one level above.

Comment: Can you supply us with some code, so we can figure out what the actual problem may be?

Comment: Sorry, I liked about my file organization stuff. I edited so you can see how my files are arranged now.

Comment: ˋ../tests/my_file.php` ? Have you tried this ?

Comment: @xxiane : please try answer below and check doc about path, and also the use of single/double slash when needed

Answer (score 0):

According to your folders' tree, you need to go back down one level, therefore, it should be `../tests/my_file.php`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `../tests/my_file.php`, `../my_file.php`, and `my_file.php` are all returning 404 errors. For some reason, my server defaults all relative paths to `localhost:3000/tests` anyways. So if I used `my_file.php`, it would still send me to `localhost:3000/tests/my_file.php` and give me that 404.

Comment: Have you checked how php files are chmod ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I had two very similar folders and I simply put my file in the wrong folder. It's working now. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!